# Combobox cbn_closeup event

Tags: mfc, ccombobox

I have combo box created with style CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD.i want to perform some action on command cbn_closeup.But my control is not getting this event.Even in spy++ there is no cbn_closeup sent to combo box.Please somebody help me.

Comment: Can you please post some more detail about your problem? My Visual Studio 2005 test on Droplist works well.

Comment: Please check if your header contains the method: afx_msg void OnCbnCloseUpYourComboId( void );, and if between BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(..)END_MESSAGE_MAP() there is ON_CBN_CLOSEUP( RES_ID, &YourDlgClass::OnCbnCloseUpYourComboId ).

Answer (score 1):

1. Not your Control gets the WM_COMMAND notification. The parent gets it. So you Need an ON_CBN_CLOSEUP in the parent window code.
2. If you want that your window gets the notification you Need an ON_CONTROL_REFLECT handler. But this only works if the parent window is created by the MFC too, or at least subclassed.

Comment: Should i need to create the combobox with some style so that the parent gets cbn_closeup event?

Comment: I am getting CBN_SELCHANGE event but not CBN_CLOSEUP.

Comment: The Combo Box should not have the style CBS_SIMPLE. (Statet in the MSDN for CBN_CLOSEUP) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775806(v=vs.85).aspx